# File duplication error in branch computers

Tags: database, duplicates

I just started working on managing a station and the problem I encounter is that a local branch computer in my workplace has duplicated a folder by itself and whenever I create a new file using that computer, a file with the same name will be saved into the duplicated folder. When I tried deleting the duplicated file, it also the removes the original file so I am really confused since I have never encountered a problem like this. And it only happens only to that specific folder, to which it is the main place that we store our important documents. No other computers have this specific problem. I really need some help since if an employee in our company delete the duplicated folder, the rest will follow. The system that we have has crashed several times but this problem has only appeared about one year ago as an employee told me.

I did not have a solution at all and I am totally blind so I wasn't able to do anything since I am afraid of deleting or adding files into the system.